# ETC transaction doesn't reflect in myetherwallet -help

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I just transfer ETC from my POLO account to the ledger nano s using
myetherwallet,

Ans something wired happend :

Here i dont see that i got anything

https://etherscan.io/address/0xc0fb24490fbf9daa9101e95bc3cf50b87dcf8ce0

but on that one i do see my transaction made successfully

http://gastracker.io/addr/0xc0fb24490fbf9daa9101e95bc3cf50b87dcf8ce0
but still doesnt reflect on myetherwallet ETC

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the ETC Block Explorer:

https://etcchain.com/

Your transactions:

https://etcchain.com/addr/0xc0fb24490fbf9daa9101e95bc3cf50b87dcf8ce0

Etherscan is an ETH blockchain explorer. Not an ETC blockchain explorer

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan is an Ethereum blockchain explorer, not an Ethereum *Classic* blockchain explorer. So you ETC transactions wont show on it. To see it in MyEtherWallet, you need to change your network to ETC in the top right.